# How can I import an existing project in Aptana without moving the files?

Tags: aptana-studio

I have a bunch of NetBeans projects. How can I open a folder of files in Aptana without having to use the Import > File system dialog which seems to force me to move all the existing files to a new directory?

I am running Aptana on Windows 7, (v3) and using PHP projects.

Answer (score 16):

There is a simpler solution in Studio 2 or Studio 3.

1. Create the folder in the location you want
2. Use the File View (Studio 2) or Local Files node of Project Explorer (Studio 3) to navigate to the folder.
3. Right-click > Promote to Project

Please let us know if that works for you. The only thing you can't do with that is nest one project inside another (and that's a bad idea anyway).

found here -> https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/554-workspace-and-project

Comment: Surely this should be marked as the answer? This definitely solved it for me.

Comment: When I tried this, the folder for the new project was empty. Is that's what's supposed to happen? Also, that link is broken.

Answer (score 8):

I have Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.0.8.201201201658 on Windows 7 64bits.

I simply use the menu `File -> Import`, then as the source, I select : `General -> "Existing Folder as New Project"`.
On top of the window, a sentence then reads "Converts an existing folder on disk into a new project. This does not copy the files into the workspace."

Indeed, the import does not copy/move anything. Simply, it will create its own file .project in your folder to manage the project.

Comment: Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I often do this in my development by merely creating a new project. Using the new project wizard, uncheck the "use default location" box, and use the directory of the folder you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

For Aptana Studio 3, build 3.0.4.201108101506

When you import files there is an "Advanced" button. Clicking that gives you the option to "Create links in workspace". Check the box "Create link locations relative to: PROJECT_LOC". That should link to the files without copying them and allow you to create new files in the folders.